# Programmatically execute vim commands?

Tags: vim, tdd

I'm interested in setting up a TDD environment for developing Vim scripts and rc files. As a simple example, say I want to have vim insert 8 spaces when I press the tab key. I would set up a script that did the following:

- Launch vim using a sandboxed .vimrc file
- press i
- press tab
- press esc
- press :w test_out
- assert that test_out contains '        '

by the default config in vim, this would fail. However, once I add `set expandtab` to my .vimrc file, the test will pass.

How do I programmatically issue these commands? `vim -c <commands>` is close, but seems to only work for ex mode commands. Any suggestions? This question seem to be thoroughly google-proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `vim -S <script in>` and, for your convenience, the opposite `vim -w <script out>`.

For more details on these options check VIM's documentation for the [-s](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-S) and [-w](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-w) arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Is using vim a requirement? If it isn't you are using the wrong tool for the job, sed might be more appropriate.

But if you must, you can do it with vim anyway, just call it `ex`

```
#!/bin/sh
# insert a tab as the first character of test_out
ex test_out <<EOF
s/^/^I/
wq
EOF

if [ `od -c test_out | awk 'NR == 1 {print $2}'` != '\t' ] ; then
    echo "assertion failed"; exit 1;
fi
```

Where `^I` is actually a <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Although this is a very odd approach.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to do TDD on vim plugins and the like. I suppose I could do TDD on an external shell script and then map to it from with in Vim, but that's not quite what I want. Largely I'm interested in better understanding what I am lifting from other people's .vimrc files and plugin directories.